# corb2 compatibility check with MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

Like mlcp, I dont see any compatibility comments related to corb2 with latest MarkLogic versions. Is CoRB2 compatible with all ML versions?
If not, is there a location I can refer to? I know I can test it out, but it is better to check documentation as I might miss some tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoRB2 should be compatible with all currently supported versions of MarkLogic.

Unlike MLCP, CoRB is a community driven open source effort and not an officially supported MarkLogic offering, so I would not expect to find compatibility information about CoRB versions in the MarkLogic documentation.

If there were to be a compatibility issue, it would likely be if there were a breaking change to the XCC library used to communicate with MarkLogic. Since the XCC library is a MarkLogic supported offering, you can expect that any breaking changes will be noted in the [MarkLogic release notes](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4). For instance:

- [XCC ContentSource.newSession Interface Change](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_42857)

CoRB is built and tested with the latest available XCC and MarkLogic versions. If there were to be a breaking change, it would be noted in the CoRB [README](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#downloads).